# How can I import the Typescript Subscription type from the Aurelia Store Subscribe method?

Tags: typescript, aurelia, aurelia-store

I am following the documentation for [Aurelia Store](https://aurelia.io/docs/plugins/store#subscribing-to-the-stream-of-states) on how to subscribe to the stream of store changes. When I import the typescript `Subscription` type from `rxjs` I get a typescript compilation error:
`TS2322: Type 'import("project\node_modules\aurelia-store\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscription") is not assignable to type import("project\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscription")`

Code example:

```
// app.ts
import { autoinject } from "aurelia-dependency-injection";
import { Store } from "aurelia-store";
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { State } from "./state";

@autoinject()
export class App {

  public state: State;
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private store: Store<State>) {}

  bind() {
    this.subscription = this.store.state.subscribe(
      (state) => this.state = state
    );
  }

  unbind() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

I've tried doing `import { Store, Subscription } from 'aurelia-store'` but that doesn't work either.

**EDIT:**

In response to Pierre-Luc Champigny's question:

> Are both your rxjs version (from Aurelia and your installed rxjs) the
>   same?

So, aurelia-store/package.json has rxjs version "^6.2.2" and my projects package.json is "6.3.2". So, I uninstalled my rxjs version and installed the 6.2.2 version. Now typescript is giving this error message:

> TS2322: Type
>   'import("project/node_modules/aurelia-store/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscription").Subscription'
>   is not assignable to type
>   'import("project/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscription").Subscription'.
>   Property '_parent' is protected but type 'Subscription' is not a class
>   derived from 'Subscription'.

Comment: Are both your rxjs version (from Aurelia and your installed rxjs) the same?

Comment: Aurelia rxjs is "^6.2.2" and mine is "6.3.2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm not sure why this worked but I'm answering my own question just in case someone else runs into this issue.

1. I uninstalled rxjs
2. I re-installed rxjs
3. I deleted my `node_modules` folder
4. I deleted my package-lock.json
5. I ran `npm clean cache --force`
6. I ran `npm install`

Then everything started working again :)

Comment: Can you run npm list rxjs? What version is now locally used and which one by the store?

Comment: Its using "6.3.2"

Comment: I guess the package-lock.json was the root reason for that. Great you got that fixed. Guess you can accept your own answer.